# Error When running tutorial on moveit

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I just install moveit for melodic from that tutorial:
http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html

When I run the demo example, I get that error:

```
roslaunch panda_moveit_config demo.launch
```

Error:

```
[ INFO] [1621332924.648205185]: Loading robot model 'panda'...
[ INFO] [1621332925.050765019]: Loading robot model 'panda'...
[ERROR] [1621332925.103988618]: Group 'hand' is not a chain
[ERROR] [1621332925.104022297]: Kinematics solver of type 'kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin' could not be initialized for group 'hand'
[ERROR] [1621332925.104066937]: Kinematics solver could not be instantiated for joint group hand.
```

And then I want to run the move group tutorial:

```
roslaunch moveit_tutorials move_group_interface_tutorial.launch
```

And I get that error:

```
process[move_group_interface_tutorial-1]: started with pid [14504]
[ INFO] [1621332944.240649978]: Loading robot model 'panda'...
[ERROR] [1621332944.313543425]: Group 'hand' is not a chain
[ERROR] [1621332944.313574409]: Kinematics solver of type 'kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin' could not be initialized for group 'hand'
[ERROR] [1621332944.313611102]: Kinematics solver could not be instantiated for joint group hand.
```

I see the robot arm in Rviz but I can't interact with rviz gui.
What did I made wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378505/error-when-running-tutorial-on-moveit/) by [arno](https://answers.ros.org/users/73570/arno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-05-18**:\

> could not be initialized for group 'hand'

I think you have to check your group it should be set to arm, not hand. Over here the word hand means that you are solving the kinematics of your gripper, not your panda arm.

In short, change the planning group to panda arm instead of hand. I think t this may be the issue if is not working feel free to drop a comment.

**Comment by [arno](https://answers.ros.org/users/73570/arno/) on 2021-05-19**:
Ok thank you, it works properly now

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-05-20**:
Could you make that a response @Ranjit?

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-05-20**:
Thanks! @fvd. I have to repost to answer as I did right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> could not be initialized for group 'hand'

I think you have to check your group it should be set to arm, not hand. Over here the word hand means that you are solving the kinematics of your gripper, not your panda arm.

In short, change the planning group to panda arm instead of hand. I think t this may be the issue if is not working feel free to drop a comment.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1